# ServiceMax Question - Problem Codes Export

Tags: data-export

I am not 100% sure this is the correct forum. However, hoping someone might be able to answer my question.

I haven't been able to locate a way to do a data extract from ServiceMax for the "Problem codes" section of a case.

What I am looking for is to be able to pick a product line and have the associated Problem code lists exported (Reported Problem / Observed Problem / Problem Mode / Problem Cause / Problem Location) The contents of these fields are drop down lists.

Ideally - I would love to do one export for all product lines but rather than 1 at a time - But I will take what I can get.

Thanks for any assistance that can be provided.

Comment: Hi Valybr, this community is only for salesforce related Q & A / discussions. I am not sure if your question is anything to do with Salesforce, if not you have to either find the right forum or talk to ServiceMax support directly

Comment: @VamsiKrishna ServiceMax is a ISV that offers a field service management AppExchange app, by the way.

Comment: Hi Valybr, I'm not sure if many people will know what ServiceMax is or does, but I can tell you're asking about how to run reports/export data from the system. You might find [Getting Started with Salesforce1 Reporting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_analytics_overview_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_analytics_overview_cheatsheet/) to be a useful resource. I'd also suggest contacting salesforce.com Technical Support directly for more information about reports, or even asking ServiceMax how you might accomplish this task (they *should* know).

Comment: @sfdcfox - It's not exactly reporting -  but rather within the development side of things. Thank you for your suggestions though. I'll reach out to the saleforce technical team.